# Access Report Privacy, How can I stop employees from seeing other employees reports?

Tags: forms, ms-access, report

I have a problem that I just can't wrap my head around. For a company expense database that I'm creating I have a search form that lets employees search for their expenses based on date ranges, client worked for, and project worked on. In the search form there is also a box for employee name: they enter their name here and filter for their reports.

However, my boss wants to make it so that you can't enter in other people's names in order to protect employee's privacy. The only way I can think of doing this is creating a new search form for each user and having their names hard coded into the form, disabling them from searching through other employee's expenses. This would be annoying but doable, but this brings up the fact that I'd also have to make new queries and reports for each employee as I don't know how to make one report and one query pull data from multiple forms, or if this is even possible.

Also I have separate reports for detail and summary reports, effectively meaning I'd have to create two new reports for each employee. This would make the database much more cluttered with dozens of reports in the report section and lead to a lot more work. Also if I had to make any changes I would have to go through each report to change them, so you can imagine how problematic doing it that way would be.

At the end of the day, I just want one report and one search form that stops employees from loading other employees reports. Can anyone please help me with this problem or give ideas on what to do?

My ideal solution is making a search form for each employee and having those search forms all be able to generate the same report, but I don't know how possible this is. For clarification purposes, I have a search query that runs from a master expense sheet. The search form queries the search query, and the report pulls its data from this query. Here is a picture of my search form to give an idea of what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: How stringent are your security requirements for this?  Must you prevent the users from bypassing your search form and opening the report from the Navigation pane instead.  Is the expense data stored in native Access tables or linked tables on a client-server database such as SQL Server?

Comment: Most people in my office actually don't have Access and will be using a Access run time reader to use the forms, so I'm not worried about them opening up the Access tables. The data is stored in a local query called Master Expense Sheet. I just want them to not be able to see other employees via the form. Obviously they could open the other tables and forms, but we are password protecting those and it should not be an issue. The only security I want here is within the search form, so either having it recognize them somehow or making personalized search forms as described above is the goal.

Comment: If the employee identification is available from *Master Expense Sheet* as the Windows user name, you could include a custom function in the report's record source query to filter the records accordingly.  Something like `WHERE user_name = WindowsUser()` with `WindowsUser()` as the custom function.  Is that compatible with your data and would it be adequate for your needs?  Do you still need something else so The Boss can view the report for all or selected employees?

Comment: I already have forms that let admins see all employee reports so that's not an issue it's limiting the employee view. The WindowsUser function sounds interesting...

Comment: I kind of suck at file paths and user names so how would I recognize the individual users computer? I'd want the formula to be something like this
cboEmployee = WindowsUser()
where I can convert the WindowsUser() to the correct employee name. But for the record, nowhere in my database do I currently have the WindowsUser name. also this is over a company network so it will be differnet computers, not just one computer. can this still work?

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a faulty assumption.  So how did you intend to inform Access about the identity of the user who is currently at the keyboard?  Have you built some type of login feature in your application?

Comment: No. Do you think that would be a good way to go? I've seen tutorials and guides and although it may take a bit of time it doesn't seem unfeasible. Also that would solve the issue of having to make multiple search forms/reports/queries and save a lot of space in the database. I would really like this approach.

Comment: So it's just a matter of if I can make a login form (with a password), could I use this login data to protect employee reports and have the search form be hard coded to what the user entered as their login. The login could be their employee name matched exactly to their name in the system. Could this work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72609/discussion-between-hansup-and-regulardude).